# PHP array, selecting a printing a specific element and its content

Tags: php, arrays, json, printing, steam-web-api

What I am trying to do is basically select an array inside of an array and print its contents that I wish to print. Here is the array.

```
{"success":true,"rgInventory":{"3480848569":{"id":"3480848569","classid":"991959905","instanceid":"0","amount":"1","pos":1},"3480576615":{"id":"3480576615","classid":"937248085","instanceid":"188530139","amount":"1","pos":2},"3480546604":{"id":"3480546604","classid":"1289504012","instanceid":"188530139","amount":"1","pos":3},"3480019616":{"id":"3480019616","classid":"1287503583","instanceid":"188530139","amount":"1","pos":4},"3480018692":{"id":"3480018692","classid":"1287539933","instanceid":"188530139","amount":"1","pos":5},"3468858273":{"id":"3468858273","classid":"310796325","instanceid":"188531406","amount":"1","pos":6},"3461024351":{"id":"3461024351","classid":"1285429560","instanceid":"0","amount":"1","pos":7},"3458814606":{"id":"3458814606","classid":"1285140836","instanceid":"188531307","amount":"1","pos":8},"3456892821":{"id":"3456892821","classid":"1283034897","instanceid":"188530398","amount":"1","pos":9},"3446207634":{"id":"3446207634","classid":"1280315186","instanceid":"0","amount":"1","pos":10},"3243469958":{"id":"3243469958","classid":"1232873338","instanceid":"480085569","amount":"1","pos":11},"3144270103":{"id":"3144270103","classid":"1290987654","instanceid":"1210747767","amount":"1","pos":12}}
```

I wish to print "rgInventory" and within that array I want to not only print the main items but also the some of the contents inside of them sich as id and classid.

Here is my code.

```
<?php
                if(empty($_SESSION['steamid'])){
                    echo 'Please sign in to view your items.';
                }else{
                    $id = $steamprofile['steamid'];
                    $key = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
                    if($id != null){
                        $link = file_get_contents('http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/'.$id.'/inventory/json/730/2');
                        $inventory = json_decode($link, true);
                        //print_r ($inventory);
                        print(sizeof($inventory));
                        foreach($inventory as $item => $id){
                            for($x = 0; sizeof($item[1]) <= $x; $x+=0){
                                echo 'ID: '.$id;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ?>
```

This is me just trying to figure out how this works. Arrays kind of confuse me so any explanation will help and be much appreciated.

Comment: Where does `$steamprofile` come from? It is never set in your code. Also, the JSON appears to be invalid... you never check the return value of `json_decode`.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen '$steamprofile' is included elsewhere and the json is valid you just cant recover it unless you have the steam id (Which is given upon login on my site and stored in '$steamprofile'. I have no problem getting the array what so ever its just shorting through it as mention in op.

However if you must see it here it is: http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561197994925827/inventory/json/730/2

Comment: Your json array is missing a curly bracket at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.

```
if ($inventory['success']) { print "SUCCESS = TRUE<br>"; }
                                foreach ($inventory['rgDescriptions'] as $rgDescription) {
                                    for($i = 0; sizeof($rgDescription['market_name']) > $i; $i++){
                                        if(isset($rgDescription['market_name'])){
                                            print '<td>'.$rgDescription['market_name'].'</td>';
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
```

Thank you Dean for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Taking your json string and adding a curly bracket at the end you can then get the data out with json_decode

e.g.

```
$link = '{"success":true,"rgInventory":{"3480848569":{"id":"3480848569","classid":"991959905","instanceid":"0","amount":"1","pos":1},"3480576615":{"id":"3480576615","classid":"937248085","instanceid":"188530139","amount":"1","pos":2},"3480546604":{"id":"3480546604","classid":"1289504012","instanceid":"188530139","amount":"1","pos":3},"3480019616":{"id":"3480019616","classid":"1287503583","instanceid":"188530139","amount":"1","pos":4},"3480018692":{"id":"3480018692","classid":"1287539933","instanceid":"188530139","amount":"1","pos":5},"3468858273":{"id":"3468858273","classid":"310796325","instanceid":"188531406","amount":"1","pos":6},"3461024351":{"id":"3461024351","classid":"1285429560","instanceid":"0","amount":"1","pos":7},"3458814606":{"id":"3458814606","classid":"1285140836","instanceid":"188531307","amount":"1","pos":8},"3456892821":{"id":"3456892821","classid":"1283034897","instanceid":"188530398","amount":"1","pos":9},"3446207634":{"id":"3446207634","classid":"1280315186","instanceid":"0","amount":"1","pos":10},"3243469958":{"id":"3243469958","classid":"1232873338","instanceid":"480085569","amount":"1","pos":11},"3144270103":{"id":"3144270103","classid":"1290987654","instanceid":"1210747767","amount":"1","pos":12}}}';

$inventory = json_decode($link, true);

if ($inventory['success']) { print "SUCCESS = TRUE<br>"; }
foreach ($inventory['rgInventory'] as $rgInventory) {
    foreach ($rgInventory as $key => $value) {
        print "$key=$value, ";
    }
    print "<br>";
}
```

This will output:

```
SUCCESS = TRUE
id=3480848569, classid=991959905, instanceid=0, amount=1, pos=1,
id=3480576615, classid=937248085, instanceid=188530139, amount=1, pos=2,
id=3480546604, classid=1289504012, instanceid=188530139, amount=1, pos=3,
id=3480019616, classid=1287503583, instanceid=188530139, amount=1, pos=4,
id=3480018692, classid=1287539933, instanceid=188530139, amount=1, pos=5,
id=3468858273, classid=310796325, instanceid=188531406, amount=1, pos=6,
id=3461024351, classid=1285429560, instanceid=0, amount=1, pos=7,
id=3458814606, classid=1285140836, instanceid=188531307, amount=1, pos=8,
id=3456892821, classid=1283034897, instanceid=188530398, amount=1, pos=9,
id=3446207634, classid=1280315186, instanceid=0, amount=1, pos=10,
id=3243469958, classid=1232873338, instanceid=480085569, amount=1, pos=11,
id=3144270103, classid=1290987654, instanceid=1210747767, amount=1, pos=12,
```

You can use online tools for checking json coding such as http://json.parser.online.fr/

Also, whilst you are working on the various arrays that come out, you can use var_dump()

e.g.

```
var_dump($rgInventory);
```

which will show you the make up of the array so you know how to get to the parts you need.

Comment: The array isnt a set array, its via a url that updates all the time, the one I posted was just an example.

Comment: If the structure of the json changes then that would just need some logic to work out what it is before pulling out the content you need.